# BufferedReader does not read the complete file

Tags: java, java-stream, inputstream, bufferedreader, filereader

I want to read the "airports.dat" file. But BufferedReader does read this file completely. My code is as follows:

```
public class AirportInformation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("airports.dat");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx) {
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

}

airports.dat file contains the following data:

> 1,"Goroka","Goroka","Papua New
>   Guinea","GKA","AYGA",-6.081689,145.391881,5282,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
>   2,"Madang","Madang","Papua New
>   Guinea","MAG","AYMD",-5.207083,145.7887,20,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
>   3,"Mount Hagen","Mount Hagen","Papua New
>   Guinea","HGU","AYMH",-5.826789,144.295861,5388,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
>   4,"Nadzab","Nadzab","Papua New
>   Guinea","LAE","AYNZ",-6.569828,146.726242,239,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
>   5,"Port Moresby Jacksons Intl","Port Moresby","Papua New
>   Guinea","POM","AYPY",-9.443383,147.22005,146,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
>   6,"Wewak Intl","Wewak","Papua New
>   Guinea","WWK","AYWK",-3.583828,143.669186,19,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
>   7,"Narsarsuaq","Narssarssuaq","Greenland","UAK","BGBW",61.160517,-45.425978,112,-3,"E","America/Godthab"
>   8,"Nuuk","Godthaab","Greenland","GOH","BGGH",64.190922,-51.678064,283,-3,"E","America/Godthab"
>   9,"Sondre
>   Stromfjord","Sondrestrom","Greenland","SFJ","BGSF",67.016969,-50.689325,165,-3,"E","America/Godthab"
>   10,"Thule Air
>   Base","Thule","Greenland","THU","BGTL",76.531203,-68.703161,251,-4,"E","America/Thule"
>   11,"Akureyri","Akureyri","Iceland","AEY","BIAR",65.659994,-18.072703,6,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   12,"Egilsstadir","Egilsstadir","Iceland","EGS","BIEG",65.283333,-14.401389,76,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   13,"Hornafjordur","Hofn","Iceland","HFN","BIHN",64.295556,-15.227222,24,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   14,"Husavik","Husavik","Iceland","HZK","BIHU",65.952328,-17.425978,48,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   15,"Isafjordur","Isafjordur","Iceland","IFJ","BIIS",66.058056,-23.135278,8,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   16,"Keflavik International
>   Airport","Keflavik","Iceland","KEF","BIKF",63.985,-22.605556,171,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   17,"Patreksfjordur","Patreksfjordur","Iceland","PFJ","BIPA",65.555833,-23.965,11,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   18,"Reykjavik","Reykjavik","Iceland","RKV","BIRK",64.13,-21.940556,48,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   19,"Siglufjordur","Siglufjordur","Iceland","SIJ","BISI",66.133333,-18.916667,10,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   20,"Vestmannaeyjar","Vestmannaeyjar","Iceland","VEY","BIVM",63.424303,-20.278875,326,0,"N","Atlantic/Reykjavik"
>   ...... ......

up to 8107 lines.

When I read this file with the above code only a chuck of this file is read. Please guide how can I read this complete file?

Comment: 1. You say only "a chuck" is read? Which one? Something from the start? Random lines?
2. You catch an exception, but print nothing. Print at least `ioEx.getMessage()` or better yet call `ioEx.printStackTrace`.

Comment: This code does not through an exception and only reads the last 758 lines.

Comment: The *last* 758 lines? Are you sure that it's not just whatever you output it to cutting of after a buffer fills? Could you try incrementing a counter in the loop and printing its value at the end to verify that?

Comment: Yes, it reads only the last 758 lines. I check this by using a counter variable. The counter shows that the loop runs exactly 8107 times but only the last 758 lines are printed out.

Comment: I'm **pretty sure** that the issue is with whatever it *prints into* (i.e. your IDE window or command shell, depending on how you launch it). That probably has a limited scroll-back buffer and you only end up seeing the end of the output, even though the program prints all of it. Try making it print only every second or third line and you'll start seeing earlier lines appear.

Comment: It means that there is nothing wrong with my code. BufferedReader reads all the lines but only few lines are shown due to limited scroll-back buffer of the console. Am I right?

Comment: That is my assumption, yes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I check this problem by storing each line in ArrayList. It confirms that all the data is properly read by BufferedReader. Thanks for your guidance.